# Problem when running iOS simulator device with react native

Tags: ios, react-native

hi I'm new to react native. I just got a problem when built my react native project with my iOS simulator. I copied the [Hello World example](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tutorial) and run but it showed dark screen. It's OK with android simulator.

[image: my capture screen]

Comment: Check your Xcode console log cmd+y (i think). And whilst the simulator is the active view hit cmd+D and select 'Debug Javascript remotely' Then you can see the JS logs

Comment: oh it worked thank you